# Typescript: Difference between two type of function decleration?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am learning TypeScript with React. 
I have tried to declare a function component and also declare a normal function, and don't know why it is different.

Work:

```js
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>Something</div>
  );
}
```

```
const add = (x: number, y: number): number => {
  return x + y;
}
```

Don't work:

```js
const App = (): React.FC => {
  return (
    <div>Something</div>
  );
}
```

```
const add: number = (x: number, y: number) => {
  return x + y;
}
```

As I know they are both define a type for a function, but why it works differently?

Comment: In the first case you type whole function and that's correct. In the second case you type only return value of function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are couple of differences:

As you write:

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>Something</div>
  );
}
```

The type of `App` is `React.FC` which is a function which returns a JSX.

Otherwise, you write:

```
const App = (): React.FC => {
  return (
    <div>Something</div>
  );
}
```

The variable `App` will return the `React.SFC` which is a function which returns JSX then as following (the correct result):

```
const App = (): React.FC => {
  return () => (
    <div>Something</div>
  );
}
```

Likewise, for your function.